# how to write criteria Query for Mongodb Group Aggregation

Tags: spring, mongodb, hibernate

Mongodb `$group` :

```
db.careLogBean.aggregate([{
    $unwind: "$comments"
}, {
    $sort: {
        "comments.time": -1
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$_id",
        careGiverId: {
            $first: "$careGiverId"
        },
        careGiverName: {
            $first: "$careGiverName"
        },
        comments: {
            $push: "$comments"
        }
    }
}])
```

In mongodb `$group` aggretion things... how to write in java criteria
                   query language...

Comment: Can you please  show what you have tried so far ?

Comment: sorry for the late replay veeram..

Comment: DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", new BasicDBObject("_id", "$name","$salary"));

Comment: No problem. Your `$group` part of the query in the post doesn't look right. Are you sure you've the working query ?

Comment: yes...actually   my requirement is below

Comment: db.careLogBean.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$comments"}, 
  {$sort: {"comments.time":-1}}, 
  {$group: {_id:"$_id",careGiverId : { $first: "$careGiverId" }, careGiverName : { $first: "$careGiverName" }, comments: {$push:"$comments"}}}
]);

Comment: this is main query for mongodb how i am write for java query for this

Comment: i am trying but the query is getting error on $group

Comment: What error do you get ? Please update the question with the correct query and the error and the spring mongodb version you use.

Comment: in db level it's fine.....it gives result....but how to convert into java criteria query.....for that

Comment: i mean how to apply aggregation query in daoimpl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below aggregation.

```
import static org.springframework.data.domain.Sort.Direction.DESC;
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.*;

Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
       unwind("comments"),
       sort(DESC, "comments.time"), 
       group("_id")
          .first("careGiverId").as("careGiverId")
          .first("careGiverName").as("careGiverName")
          .push("comments").as("comments"));

List<BasicDBObject> dbObjects = mongoOperations.aggregate(aggregation , collection_name, BasicDBObject.class).getMappedResults();
```

You can adjust the last statement based on your set up.

Comment: am checking now ..let you know what happend

Comment: You are welcome. You can check the tick box left off  answer. For more info  http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer